# Prove $I-YY^\dagger$ is a projection operator for $N(Y)$

Tags: matrices

Let $Y\in \mathbb{R}^{m*m}$ be a symmetric matrix and how to prove $I-YY^\dagger$ is a projection operator for $N(Y)$? I know $I-Y^\dagger Y$ is a projection operator for $N(Y)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does $N(Y) = \ker Y = \{ y \mid Yy = 0\}$?

Comment: @RobertLewis yes

Answer (score 0):

How can you rewrite $I-YY^\dagger$ if you know Y is symmetric and you already know that $I-Y^\dagger Y$ is a projection operator?

Answer (score 0):

Since $Y$ is real symmetric,

$Y^\dagger = Y^T = Y; \tag 1$

thus

$Y^\dagger Y = YY^\dagger = Y^2, \tag 2$

whence

$I - Y^\dagger Y = I -  YY^\dagger = I - Y^2; \tag 3$

it therefore follows that $I - YY^\dagger$ is a projection onto $N(Y)$ if and only if $I - Y^\dagger Y$ is . . .

Comment: why is $Y^\dagger = Y^T$ true?

Comment: @Jingyang:  Because $Y$ is real and symmetric.